# Uniform convergence of sum $(1/n)^x$

Tags: summation, uniform-convergence

I'm trying to check where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^x$ uniformly converges on $(1,\infty)$. I want to do that with the Cauchy criteria. For every $\epsilon$>0 exists an $N>0$ so that for all $n>N$ and all natural $P$: 
$$|\sum_{n=1}^{P}1/n^x|<\epsilon, \quad \text{for all} \ x>1.
$$ 
(a subsequence of a known convergent sum). So for all $n>N$ and for all natural $P$ and $x>1$: 
$$
|\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+P}1/k^x|\leq|\sum_{n=1}^{P}1/n^x|<\epsilon.
$$
Thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n^x$ uniformly converges for every $x>1$. Now I know this is probably lacking/wrong, so I ask you guys to correct me please :) Thanks.(sorry for not putting proper spacing, I don't know how to do that yet).

Comment: There is a uniform convergence on each $[a,\infty)$, $a>1$ not over $(1,\infty)$. One may use the integral test of convergence to see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ on an interval $I$ means: $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$|f_N(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon,\quad\forall N>n_0,\forall x\in I,$$
This is equivalent to say that
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sup_{x\in I}|f_N(x)-f(x)|=0.$$
Now back to the question, note that
$$\sup_{x\in(1,\infty)}\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}\geq \sup_{x\in(1,\infty)}\sum_{n=N+1}^M \frac{1}{n^x}=\sum_{n=N+1}^M\frac{1}{n},\quad\forall M>N+1$$
it follows that
$$\sup_{x\in(1,\infty)}\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}\geq\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{n=N+1}^M\frac{1}{n}=+\infty.$$
Thus
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sup_{x\in(1,+\infty)}\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x}=+\infty,$$
and therefore the series does not converge uniformly on $(1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks, but how about on [a,$\infty$) a>1? like the guy who commented on my post said?

Comment: It's uniformly convergent on $[a,\infty)$ when $a>1$, because $$\sup_{x\in[a,\infty)}\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^x}\leq\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^a}\to 0$$ as $N\to\infty$.